# How can I use munin-node apache_ with basic authentication?

Tags: munin, http-basic-authentication

`munin-node-configure --suggest` tells me that the `apache_*` nodes cannot be used:

```
apache_accesses            | no   | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]   
apache_processes           | no   | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]   
apache_volume              | no   | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]
```

This is correct: the virtual-host is the only accessible site and is put behind a simple .htaccess login.

How can I configure the `apache_*` nodes to login with basic authentication? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into the sourcecode for the apache_ nodes, I found the documentation on this issue in there:

```
If you need authenticated access to the URL you can specify the
username and password in the URL.  For example:

  [apache_volume]
     env.url http://munin:spamalot@localhost/server-status?auto
```

This works.