# munin-node apache_ with basic authentication - please be more specific

Tags: apache-2.2, munin

Can someone please explain this to me:

In this answer:
[How can I use munin-node apache_ with basic authentication?](https://serverfault.com/questions/271844/munin-node-apache-with-basic-authentication)

there is a line saying:

> If you need authenticated access to the URL you can specify the
>   username and password in the URL.  For example:
>
> ```
> [apache_volume]
>   <env.url http://munin:spamalot@localhost/server-status?auto>
> ```

I do not understand this.

If for example username is `xxxx` and password is `yyyy` how would I change the:
`<env.url http://munin:spamalot@localhost/server-status?auto>`
to corespond to username `xxxx` and password `yyyy`?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in front of you

```
http://munin:spamalot@localhost/server-status?auto
```

become

```
http://xxxx:yyyy@localhost/server-status?auto
```

Comment: Thanks, I tryed but I stil got the:

/usr/sbin/munin-node-configure --suggest :

apache_accesses | yes | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]

apache_processes | yes | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]

apache_volume | yes | no [Port 80: Authorization Required]

I don't know how to fix this.

I have .htaccess files in: /server-status folder , and
/var/cache/munin/www

If I remove .httaccess from those folders then everythings works....?

I do not know what am I doing wrong??

Please help.